# question about inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> given $u\in\mathbb{F}^n$ such as $\langle v,u \rangle=0$ for each $v\in\mathbb{F}^n$.
>
> prove that $u=\underline{0}$.

by contradiction, assume that $u \neq \underline{0}$. now, because $v$ and $u$ are both in $\mathbb{F}^n$ I can choose $v=u$ so: $\langle v,u \rangle = \langle u,u \rangle = 0$.
and from positivity this means that $u=\underline{0}$.

Is this correct?
I'm not sure because I learn this as part of diagonalization and don't see how this is connected to the topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, your argument is true.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: thank you.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space.

Comment: General comment on style - the contradiction is not needed. The exact same argument follows without the contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No contradiction is needed:
$$
0 = u \cdot u = \lVert u \rVert^2 = \sum_i \left|u_i\right|^2 
\Rightarrow u_i = 0
\Rightarrow u = 0
$$

Comment: @GitGud Thanks, I forgot to make it $\mathbb{C}$-proof.